# Formatting Display Precision

Tags: functions, display

I have defined the following function in *Mathematica*,

```
f[n_,q_] = Log[(n+q-1)!/(q!*(n-1)!)];
```

When putting in a large number, say `f[650,110]`, the result is

```
Log[10408292...]
```

when I want the output to give me the evaluation of the natural logarithm (which ends up being about 310 in this case). I have made several attempts including changing the display precision in the settings - didn't work, setting the precision in the function,

```
f[n_,q_] = SetPrecision[Log[(n+q-1)!/(q!*(n-1)!)],15];
```

which gives this output

```
Log[1.040829240901916×10^135]
```

as well as specifically telling it to display in scientific notation,

```
f[n_,q_] = ScientificForm[Log[(n+q-1)!/(q!*(n-1)!)]];
```

which gives the same display as setting the precision. Could anyone help me with this display problem, please?

Comment: I am not sure what display you are going for, but if you just want a simple number, use real input instead of exact input, such as f[650.,110] or you could use N[f[650,110]].  Also you are missing ) after ! in your second 2 equations.  I get a simple decimal number when executing your SetPrecision equation after correction.

Comment: `Binomial[]` is built-in, so you can use `Log[Binomial[n + q - 1, q]]`. Nevertheless, that can still overflow, so consider using the expression in terms of `LogGamma[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[n_, q_] := Log[(n + q - 1)!/(q!*(n - 1)!)]
```

Maybe one these will work for you.

```
f[650, 110] // N
```

> `310.889`

or

```
f[650., 110.]
```

> `310.889005296658`